# Reusing same Static IP address on a guest VM on RHEL KVM Hypervisor from a VM which is shut down

Tags: ip, routing, ipv6, ip-address

I have a KVM Hypervisor running RHEL where I can spawn multiple guest VMs but I have a very limited number of Static IP addresses available.

If I intend to reuse these IPs on VMs after shutting down the guest VMs. What points should I take note of when I shut down a VM and reuse the same IP on a different VM

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to set up a machine with a Static IP (i.e. include DNS servers, routing gateways) then there is nothing specific you need to note.

Just ensure that you don't have two machines running at the same time with either the same IP address or the same MAC address